# Using network files locally for increased performance

Tags: windows-10, sync, network-drive

In my workplace we are provided a mapped network drive to store all of our important files. The network drives have their own backup procedures in place. Thus we are required to keep all our important documents.

My problem is that I work with rather large files (1-5GB) regularly. Opening and Saving these files to/from the network drive can take quite a while (5-10min) so I've gone to moving these files to my local C:\ drive while working on them. Unfortunately, this means that any changes I make aren't being backed up unless I remember to copy the files back on to the network. And its not uncommon to forget for one reason or another. I'd like a more robust way to keep these files on the network drive yet be able to work with them locally.

My immediate thought was a syncing solution much like dropbox. I'd like to be able to manage the solution only from my workstation.

**Is there a way to work with local files and have any changes automatically pushed to a mapped network drive?**

Comment: The question itself is not specific to corporate IT support and networks (if it was, it would be off-topic here on Super User), but still in your case this is the job for the IT department in your workplace. Did you contact them and ask for help? Implementing any contraption behind their back may not be a good idea.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Is there a better SE where this would be on topic? As far as IT department, its a small company so there really isn't an IT department to ask to solve this for me. Any IT work it outsourced on an as needed basis.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't think there is a better SE site. The question (bold text) is on-topic here, it's the context that makes asking it here somewhat questionable and I just wanted to make sure you're taking the best available course of actions. I'm not going to vote to close your question as off-topic; so far nobody voted. The question will benefit if you show some research effort. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Is there any chance the files you would work with could get changed by another user while you're working with them locally?

Comment: On Linux, there's a utility called `rsync` -- when you run it, it can keep two directories in sync, only copying what actually changed. The two directories (aka folders) are usually one remote & one local; but, the two directories can both be local. There are some windows ports of rsync, eg, deltacopy ( http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp ), and in theory, you could have a local folder for your "work", and another network shared folder on the same pc, and let deltacopy keep the two in sync -- either by running it on demand as necessary, or schedule it to run periodically.